# nVidia Control Panel resets Gamma setting after restart

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-graphics-card, display-settings

Yesterday i bought a GeForce 560 Ti video card but unfortunately there is a problem.

I set the gamma level in nVidia Control Panel to 0.65 but when I shut down or restart the PC the **gamma is restored to its original state**. The slider in the control panel is still adjusted to 0,65 but the gamma is set to original level.

I am running Windows 7 32 Bit and the latest nVidia driver.Motherboard is Asrock P67 Pro3. How can I let the driver remember the gamma setting?

Comment: Did you try to open the Control Panel with administrator privileges?